# create new columns with blank values, not null/ Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def add_default_columns(df):
# Define a dictionary with default values for each column as empty strings
default_values = {
    'A': '',
    'B': '',
    'C': '',
    'Direction': 'D',
}

# Use the default_values dictionary to add the columns with empty strings as default values
for col, value in default_values.items():
    df[col] = value

return df

temp_file= add_default_columns(df)
temp_file.to_csv(temp_path_pd, index=False)
```

i want to add few columns as blank values to a dataframe as type object, i am able to achieve that, but after writing it to Azure datalake and while reading it back, these columns do not have blank values but instead they are coming again as null.
How can i get blank values even after reading it back.?

Note: i want to only write using pandas , not spark.

Comment: This looks like an issue with how you read the data, the empty string is likely considered as NaN. Btw, you can simplify your code using `df.assign(**default_values)` instead of the loop.

Comment: @mozway added my comments below

Answer (score 0):

By default, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) treats empty strings as NaNs, you might want to pass `keep_default_na=False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2], 'Y': [3, 4]})

def add_default_columns(df):
    # Define a dictionary with default values for each column as empty strings
    default_values = {
        'A': '',
        'B': '',
        'C': '',
        'Direction': 'D',
    }
    return df.assign(**default_values)


add_default_columns(df).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)


df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', keep_default_na=False)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y A B C Direction
0  1  3               D
1  2  4               D
```

Comment: for reading i am using spark and i have to use spark for that , and writing from spark i cant change that for other reasons, so writing from pandas and reading from spark ?

Comment: `spark.read.format('csv').options(header = 'true', nullValue='')` FYI , i have tried similar ways of reading using spark, didn't work.